# Tithing in the churches today

Tags: genesis, hebrew, matthew, luke, leviticus

Q. Why are there so many debates about tithing today?

JC Pennys' chain of malls in America has the testimony of tithing; why is it negated today?
Looking unto Abraham, he gave a tithe, Jacob vowed and gave a tithe, even before Moses came and it was enshrined into the law.
Why is it difficult to accept today that is the way of God for us financially?
Abraham did not give it in a temple and it was accepted, Jacob did not give it in a temple as well, Heb 7:7-9 also mentioned that 'men that died received tithes but there he receiveth, with the witness that he liveth.'

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the site tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.  You will need a specific Bible passage to analyze to get any answers.

Comment: The question may be voted for closure on the grounds that it references a text but is not actually about that text and its meaning or interpretation. The site focuses on _hermeneutic_ analysis, not debate or discussion of biblical topics.

Comment: Hebrews 7:8 is very interesting to me. People are giving in offering plates/credit transations on the Earth, but Christ the High Priest is receiving the spiritual offering on behalf of God. Perhaps a lack of understanding of the heavenly reality is what leads people to withhold/debate the Biblical validity of tithing. Because giving heavenly offerings is an incredible incentive to tithe whether or not you trust the earthly handler.

Answer (score 3):

Tithing becomes a matter of debate whenever anyone tries to turn it into a law which Christians must obey.

For "we are discharged from the law, dead to that which held us captive, so that we serve not under the old written code but in the new life of the Spirit" (Romans ch7 v6, RSV). Christians will now give to the church when the Spirit tells them to give, not when the law of Moses tells them to give.

And if someone says "Ah, but tithing is in Genesis", the answer to that quibble is to be found in Galatians. Paul says "You who desire to be under the law, do you not hear the law?"(Galatians ch4 v21) and he then, specifically, asks them to hear a story out of Genesis (viz. the story of Isaac and Ishmael). In other words, when Paul says "the law", he includes the book of Genesis in that expression along with the rest of the Pentateuch.

So if anyone tries to renew the law of tithing and impose it upon Christians, anyone else who has been reading Paul will raise objections.

Comment: Up-voted +1 despite that the question is probably off-topic. But some might say to you 'Melchizedek is a type of Christ and therefore, in effect, Abraham gave a tenth to Christ' and we should follow that example. And your argument about Gal 4:21 becomes redundant for Paul gives _an example of faithful conduct_ by referencing Genesis. _He does not point to a legal commandment._ Therefore, tithing to Melchizedek/Christ becomes an _example_ of faithful behaviour. Not a legal demand.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, people struggle with returning their tithes to God when they see it as giving money *to people*.  True, tithes are for the support of the clergy, the "Levites" among us.  However, it is not the Levite who requires the tithe of us--it is God Himself.  To withhold our tithes means we are robbing God.  God says so Himself.

> Will a man rob God? Yet ye have robbed me. But ye say, Wherein have we
> robbed thee? In tithes and offerings. (Malachi 3:8, KJV)

He goes on to say . . .

> Bring ye all the tithes into the storehouse, that there may be meat in
> mine house, and prove me now herewith, saith the LORD of hosts, if I
> will not open you the windows of heaven, and pour you out a blessing,
> that there shall not be room enough to receive it. (Malachi 3:10, KJV)

The interesting thing, for those who see this as no longer binding, is that in verse 6, just prior to these verses, God says "I am Yahweh, I do not change."  Why would God change this requirement?  God has a legitimate right to be acknowledged as the rightful owner of all that we have.  We are simply His stewards, taking care of His possessions.  If He asks a mere ten percent of what we have, we should happily give it, knowing that we owe even the remaining ninety percent to Him.

The principal reason people become averse to tithing today is the same reason that people detested the sacrifices in the days of Eli's sons, Hophni and Phinehas.

The following shameful record of these men stands recorded in scripture.

> Now the sons of Eli were sons of Belial; they knew not the LORD. (1
> Samuel 2:12, KJV)
>
> And if any man said unto him, Let them not fail to burn the fat
> presently, and then take as much as thy soul desireth; then he would
> answer him, Nay; but thou shalt give it me now: and if not, **I will
> take it by force.** (1 Samuel 2:16, KJV)

The men were doing that which was unlawful, and were requiring it of the worshipers who came--using force, if necessary, to get what they wanted.  And the Biblical record is this:

> Wherefore the sin of the young men was very great before the LORD:
> **for men abhorred the offering of the LORD.** (1 Samuel 2:17, KJV)

The same is true today.  God's requirements have not changed--but men's abuse of the tithes and offerings dedicated for the service of God have caused people to seek excuses for no longer fulfilling their duty to God.  Those who see the monies as going to merely *human* recipients will soon find reason to give up the practice--but God has not asked us to look to men, but to Himself.  Tithing is not only for the benefit of the clergy; it is for the benefit of the giver, who learns unselfishness and gratitude toward God through the regular habit of tithing.

Comment: Isn't it interesting that Malachi says "...and offerings" seeming to imply that the spirit-led response to God includes both tithes and offerings (financial, thank offerings, etc).